# Press key with pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Extremely straightforward question.

Just want to press a keyboard key. Like enter, using pywin auto. I don't want to press it in the context of any application window.

Just a raw keypress of a keyboard key, like a or enter or backspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
# from pywinauto.SendKeysCtypes import SendKeys # old for pywinauto==0.5.x
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

send_keys('some text{ENTER 2}some more textt{BACKSPACE}', with_spaces=True)
```

Docs:
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html

P.S. `SendKeysCtypes` was renamed to `keyboard` in pywinauto 0.6.0+.

Comment: Thank you, the **"{ENTER}"** functionality worked. How broadly is this supported? Can I have all the modifier keystrokes to do this? Like Alt, Ctrl Tab. Also can I make combinations in sendkeysCtypes? Like "Ctrl + 1 or Ctrl + C`"

Comment: It's possible. I've just described it in the new docs for renamed keyboard module (other things are unchanged): http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html

Comment: latest documentation: http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html?highlight=SendKeys

Comment: @VasilyRyabov running this (only) `pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys  
SendKeys('^a^x')` only send `^A^X` to the python console. (It doesn't select all/copy text on the active windows). Any idea how to makes it work?

Comment: Console is not a GUI application. Just try to press the same keys manually. It will print the same symbols. :)

Comment: If you want to capture stdout of the command line process you spawned, it's better to use standard module `subprocess`.

Comment: I've just used `from pywinauto.SendKeysCtypes import SendKeys` (as in your answer) and received 'ImportError: No module named 'pywinauto.SendKeysCtypes''. Please, what should we be using now?

Comment: Currently it should be `from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys` and it's mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the include to get the code working:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys, KeySequenceError

send_keys('some text{ENTER 2}some more textt{BACKSPACE}', with_spaces=True)
```

Comment: Saved me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got this running for my game, and it works on notepad.exe too

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="win32").connect(path="Mario")
# app.MarioClass.minimize() # if you want to minimized
app.MarioClass.send_keystrokes('Hi {ENTER}')
```